# How do I plot a circle with points inside it in R?

Tags: r, geometry

I need to plot a circle centered at `(0,0)` in R. Then I would like to plot points in that circle specified in radius and degrees. Could anyone point me in the right direction for this task?

Comment: Do you mean *radius* and degrees?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In base graphics:

```
r <- 3*runif(10)
degs <- 360*runif(10)

# First you want to convert the degrees to radians

theta <- 2*pi*degs/360

# Plot your points by converting to cartesian

plot(r*sin(theta),r*cos(theta),xlim=c(-max(r),max(r)),ylim=c(-max(r),max(r)))

# Add a circle around the points

polygon(max(r)*sin(seq(0,2*pi,length.out=100)),max(r)*cos(seq(0,2*pi,length.out=100)))
```

Note that at least one of the points will be on the border of the circle, so if you dont want this you would have replace of the `max(r)` statments with something like `1.1*max(r)`

Comment: Add `, asp = 1` to the plot statement for the final image to display as a circle instead of an oval.

Answer (score 2):

To do this with ggplot2, you need to use `coord_polar`, ggplot2 will do all the transformations for you. An example in code:

```
library(ggplot2)
# I use the builtin dataset 'cars'
# Normal points plot
ggplot(aes(x = speed, y = dist), data = cars) + geom_point()
```

[image]

```
# With polar coordinates
ggplot(aes(x = speed, y = dist), data = cars) + geom_point() + 
     coord_polar(theta = "dist")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that looks perfect, but I keep getting `Error in match.arg(theta, c("x", "y")) : 'arg' should be one of “x”, “y”`

Comment: the problem with this is that I can't specify location in degrees

Comment: Please post a reproducible example if you want more to the point feedback.

Comment: That example will work if `coord_polar(theta = "dist")` is changed to `coord_polar(theta = "y")`

Answer (score 0):

Use a polar system of coords.([link to wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system)).

then [transle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates)  it into Cartesian coordinate system ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system))

and then translate to screen coords ( for example 0,0 is a center of your monitor)