# Plotting world map in orthographic projection is giving "non finite points"

Tags: r, dictionary, plot, projection, orthographic

I have a shapefile of world countries, downloaded from [here](http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.zip). I can plot it in R using

```
countries <- readOGR("shp","TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3",encoding="UTF-8",stringsAsFactors=F)
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0),bg=rgb(0.3,0.4,1))
plot(countries,col=rgb(1,0.8,0.4))
```

Now I wanna plot it in orthographic projection (Earth seen from outer space), so I'm trying

```
countries <- spTransform(countries,CRS("+proj=ortho +lat_0=-10 +lon_0=-60"))
```

I also played with the x_0 and y_0 parameters (as stated [here](http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/proj_list/orthographic.html)), but I always get the error:

```
non finite transformation detected:
[1] 45.08332 39.76804      Inf      Inf
Erro em .spTransform_Polygon(input[[i]], to_args = to_args, from_args = from_args,  : 
  failure in Polygons 3 Polygon 1 points 1
Além disso: Mensagens de aviso perdidas:
In .spTransform_Polygon(input[[i]], to_args = to_args, from_args = from_args,  :
  108 projected point(s) not finite
```

sometimes in the 3rd polygon, sometimes in the 7th. Where are those "Inf" coming from? I need to change any parameter? I want to plot the map like this

[image: orthographic projection]

but centered above South America. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are trying to project all the coordinates from -180 to 180 and from -90 to 90. But it is not possible with the kind of projection you are trying to use. Try first to crop to the region you want to see projected. And I strongly recommend you to read some literature about geographic projections.

Comment: See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection_in_cartography#Mathematics for a rule of thumb on where to crop.

Comment: Thanks, Pascal. I wanna plot the whole half-world, just like the image above. I thought I would need only the central lat/long, and the algorithm would cut where needed.

Comment: Thanks, plannapus, I'll try to use this formula to crop the points. Though I think that's just stupid. There should be an easier way to make this sort of plot automatically...

Comment: In the first example (http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html) they don't need to do what you're saying. It proves there's an easier way, or not?

Comment: So @plannapus, you saw the link above? Don't you think that the function spTransform, since it calculates all the sin and cos, should already have an option to crop or not plot or anything else? Just like the example above seem to have?

Comment: @Pascal? You saw the example above?

Comment: Other point is, to crop the points hidden by Earth would destroy the polygons topology.

Comment: Problem would be solved if R didn't stop at errors. But I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the `maps` package a try. It gives a warning about the points that cannot be projected, but it does not give an error and shut the process down. With a little fiddling, namely setting the fill color for the ocean ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8473810/4055438) answer helped solve that problem), I was able to emulate the map you attached with a couple lines:

```
library(maps)

## start plot & extract coordinates from orthographic map
o <- c(-10,-60,0) # oreantation
xy <- map("world",proj="orthographic", orientation=o, bg="black")
xy <- na.omit(data.frame(do.call(cbind, xy[c("x","y")])))

## draw a circle around the points for coloring the ocean 
polygon(max(xy$x)*sin(seq(0,2*pi,length.out=100)),max(xy$y)*cos(seq(0,2*pi,length.out=100)), 
        col="blue4", border=rgb(1,1,1,0.5), lwd=2)

## overlay world map
colRamp <- colorRampPalette(c("lemonchiffon", "orangered"))
map("world",proj="orthographic", orientation=o, 
    fill=TRUE, col=colRamp(5), add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Paul, it is working. I'm doing it for an inset, giving the location of another, bigger map. How can I project the bounding box of the other map as a rectangle over this globe? (It will not be a rectangle, but a curved rectangle...) I could do it with mapproject and rect, but then I get a not curved rectangle.

Comment: There are probably easier ways, but I would manually build the coords of a rectangle, project it using `mapproject` and add it using `polygon`: `x <- seq(-60, -30, length.out=100);
y <- seq(-30, -10, length.out=100);
x <- c(x, rep(x[length(x)], length(x)), rev(x), rep(x[1], length(x)));
y <- c(rep(y[1], length(y)), y, rep(y[length(y)], length(y)), rev(y));
xy <- mapproject(x, y, proj="orthographic", orientation=o);
polygon(xy$x, xy$y)`

Comment: Yes, of course, how didn't I thought of that? ;) Thanks again!